# VBA Array within Arrays

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am currently trying to use vba to check whether a solver solution has been found already and if so generate a new one. Below is my code. There are comments to explain what is going on.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
one = 1
min_cell = Range("BF6").Value
max_cell = Range("BF7").Value
gamer = Range("BF10").Value
Dim players(1 To 200) As String 'here is the inner array
Dim lineups(1 To 200) As Variant 'here is the outer array
For i = 1 To 200
    lineups(i) = players 'assigning the players array to each spot in the lineup array
Next i
If gamer = 0 Then
    spot = "AZ3"
    accuracy = 0.00000001
ElseIf gamer = 1 Then
    spot = "BA3"
    accuracy = 0.001
End If
Dim variable As Integer
lineup_quantity = Range("BF8").Value 'denotes how many different solutions the solver should generate
max_value = 1000
Dim counter As Integer
Dim count As Integer
lineup_number = 1 'denotes the current lineup number
Dim occurences(1 To 201) As Integer
For count = lineup_number To lineup_quantity 'running solver
    Dim positions(1 To 201) As String
    Dim cell_numbers(1 To 201)
    track = 1
    Worksheets("Draftkings Lookup").Range("AI1:AI500").Copy
    Worksheets("Draftkings Lookup").Range("DZ1:DZ500").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    SolverReset
    solverok setcell:=spot, maxminval:=1, bychange:="AL" + CStr(min_cell) + ":AL" + CStr(max_cell), engine:=2
    SolverOptions Precision:=accuracy
    solveradd cellref:="AL" + CStr(min_cell) + ":AL" + CStr(max_cell), relation:=5
    solveradd cellref:=spot, relation:=1, formulatext:=max_value
    solveradd cellref:="BA6:BA11", relation:=2, formulatext:="AY6"
    solversolve userfinish:=True
    Range("BM" + CStr(count + 1)).Value = Range(spot).Value
    For counter = min_cell To max_cell
        If Range("AL" + CStr(counter)).Value = 1 Then
            players(track) = Range("B" + CStr(counter)).Value 'stores the result to of the solver and is working properly
            positions(track) = Range("C" + CStr(counter)).Value
            cell_numbers(track) = counter
            track = track + 1
        End If
    Next counter
    For counter = 1 To lineup_number 'my attempt at comparing players to each array in lineups which is not working
        For i = 1 To 8
            If lineups(counter)(i) <> players(i) Then
                GoTo hi
            End If
        Next i
        count = count - 1 'causes program to repeat current lineup
        GoTo line
hi:
    Next counter
    For i = 1 To 8
        lineups(lineup_number)(i) = players(i) 'adding the current players as an array in lineups since they don't match any prior lineups
    Next i
line:
Worksheets("Draftkings Lookup").UsedRange.Columns("AI:AI").Calculate
Next count
End Sub
```

I am still getting duplicates when I run it for a large number of lineups like 40. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's a fraction of what it was now.

Comment: "There are comments to explain what is going on." - there are?

Comment: The comments are restored.

Comment: What possible reason is there for creating 200 aliases for one array?

Comment: In the case of creating 200 separate lineups of 6 players each.

Comment: But that is exactly what you are *not* doing. There is only a single "inner array". Why not use a two-dimensional array?

Comment: Could you explain further? This is my first VBA project.

Comment: `lineups(i) = players` doesn't produce a *copy* of `players`. There is only a single declared array named `players`, which you are referring to 200 times. It would make more sense to do something like `Dim lineups(1 to 200, 1 to 6)` As String`

Comment: Ok and I would reference a spot in that array by using something like lineups(1)(1)

Comment: You would use `lineups(i,j)` to refer to player `j` in lineup `i`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Is it possible to make a comparison between two arrays or does that need to be done iteratively?

Comment: I receive wrong number of dimensions when doing what John Coleman recommends? Why is that?